# wscript.exe virus?

Tags: vba, vbscript, virus

I am using a VBA macro that uses vbscript and my antivirus software (ZoneAlarm) detects a virus on the following line of code.

```
Shell "wscript.exe " & strFile & " " & strUploadFile
```

Has anyone had the same problem? Could it be just a false positive?

EDIT:

This is the VBScript code:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
ret = WshShell.AppActivate("Choose file to upload")
Loop Until ret = True
WScript.Sleep 1000
ret = WshShell.AppActivate("Choose file to upload")
If ret = True Then

 WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & WScript.Arguments(0) & "| clip", 0, True
 WScript.Sleep 2000
 WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 WScript.Sleep 2000
 WshShell.SendKeys "^{v}"
 WScript.Sleep 2000
 WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 WScript.Sleep 2000
 WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
 WScript.Sleep 2000
 WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

End If
WScript.Sleep 500
Set WshShell = nothing
```

Comment: It's because `wscript.exe` is used to run scripts, and those scripts could be malicious in nature. See https://superuser.com/a/1300070/53953

Comment: If you are using it to call code that you have written then it is a false positive, unless for some reason you are writing viruses. Maybe `ZoneAlarm` can be configured to white-list your own macros. If the VBA code is e.g. in Excel, then you should be able (by creating a WShell object) to do this more directly then by using `Shell`.

Comment: Paste your VBScript into VBA.

Comment: Why have a VBA macro call a VBScript?

Comment: VBScript is being used to interact with an IE file upload dialog. How can I integrate the VBScript code into VBA?

Comment: Set wshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

wshShell.Run I guess this is the code to run the vbscript code without calling wscript.exe. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @Hayek same way you did it in VBScript, VBA has access to COM just like VBScript. Problem is you don't share the VBScript which makes it difficult to advise. There should be no need to use `WScript.Shell` at all, VBA can even access the Windows APIs directly which is a trick VBScript can't do. There is nothing VBScript can do that VBA can't (except maybe embed itself in really old internet browser made by Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my VBS code which got blocked by Windows Defender. I don't know why, but when I changed my code from:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

to

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

everything was fine.

Answer (score -2):

This has happened to me before. VBScript, normally, with WScript.Shell with a shell command to open an app (which could be used a a forkbomb), like in your case, AppActivate, as well as using the batch command clip to copy something to the clipboard, which could be something a virus could use, will normally trigger an Anti virus program, also as VBScript is a script running program.

Comment: Have you tried to read the sentence you just wrote? I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: What? I thought it made sence. lemme edit it.

Comment: You should really try to read that sentence out loud to someone. I'm pretty sure they will be completely lost. I've read it a few times now, but my head hurts every time I try. You could probably split that up into 5 or 6 separate sentences. A single sentence with 7 comma's (so 8 partial sentences) is very hard to understand.